# Why I can't see my developer certificate in build settings?

Tags: ios

This morning I tried many times upload my app to store, but I couldn't. And after that I deleted all the certificates from keychair and developer account. I created them again. But now I can't see them in my project. In Organizer the profiles status isnt visible!! Here is an image that relates to my problem.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what might cause my problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: The first place to check for me is usually the Organizer where all provisioning profiles (+ their validity) etc. are listed...

Comment: In Organizer the profiles status isnt visible!!

Answer (score 2):

If you renewed all of your certificates, then all provisioning profiles using these certs have become invalid. You need to renew those as well.

Once you did, import them into the Xcode organizer and make sure that no warnings about missing certificates or code signing identities are displayed if you select one.

Comment: should i delete all my Provisionings ?

Comment: So your *new* provisioning profiles are visible in organizer and no warning is given? Is the Bundle ID still the same?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't have another idea right now, but I'll keep thinking about it. Is this still working on your other projects?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to import the Apple Worldwide Developer root certificate as well.

Comment: i didnt delete it, saved just it

Comment: Everything is ok but just status isnt  visible